# failed to create process while creating new project in django

Tags: python, django, windows, django-admin

I have installed a fresh python 3.7 and django 3.1.2 but when i tried to create a new project it showed me this error i tried doing everything but nothing solved this so far.

```
C:\Users\Ahmed>django-admin startproject theapp
failed to create process.
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure python is added as a PATH in your Environment variables.
To check simply use:

```
py --version
```

Also, you can tell Django is installed and which version by running the following command in a shell prompt:

```
py -m django --version
```

If Django is installed, you should see the version of your installation. If it isn’t, you’ll get an error telling “No module named django”. If both python and Django are successfully installed, use following command to create an new django project:

```
django-admin startproject mysite
```

If you still face the same error, see [Problems running django-admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/faq/troubleshooting/#troubleshooting-django-admin).